# Hibernate 3 Lazy loading many-to-one field does not work when setting cascade to "all"

Tags: hibernate, lazy-loading, cascade, many-to-one

I have a many-to-one field defined in the mapping file with lazy="no-proxy" and cascade="none".
The bytecode instrument ant task has been done. and I get the lazy-loading working fine.

But when I change the cascade to "all", the lazy-loading doesn't work. and all the other lazy properties are also loaded eagerly.

Here my question is why the lazy-loading does not work when set cascade="all"?
and is there any solution to make the many-to-one lazy-loading works when setting cascade="all"?

When the cascade="none", after calling session.load(A.class, longid), the property emailAdr, contact and testb are not loaded, which is what I excepted.

But when changing the cascade to "all", all the lazy fields got loaded eagerly when calling session.load(A.class, longid).

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.abc.TestA" lazy="false" table="TBL_TESTA">
        <id name="oid" type="java.lang.Long" unsaved-value="null" column="OID">
            <generator class="com.abc.IdentifierGenerator"/>
        </id>
        <version column="VER_NUM" name="verNum" type="long"/>

        <property name="emailAdr" type="java.lang.String" lazy="true" column="EMAIL_ADR" >

        <many-to-one name="contact" class="com.abc.SetupContact" lazy="no-proxy" cascade="none" not-null="true">
            <column name="CNTCT_OID"/>
        </many-to-one>

        <one-to-one name="testb" class="com.abc.TestB" lazy="no-proxy" cascade="none"/>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: what do you mean by saying that lazy loading is not working?

Answer (score 0):

Lazy loading is just a hint for the ORM implementation. It might be that if you define the cascade as "all", hibernate "decides" that it is optimal for it to load the entity eagerly.

Generally it's not a problem if ORM loads lazy mapped ManyToOne objects eagerly.